# Setting getChannelData causing socket.io to crash in web audio

Tags: html, ffmpeg, socket.io, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm having an issue where whenever I transcode an audio file and send the audio buffer to the client via socket.io to be played by web audio my connection dies as soon as I perform

```
source.buffer.getChannelData(0).set(audio);
```

I'm assuming that this isn't a Socket.IO problem and that I'm only seeing the Socket.IO issue as a result of the real problem. In the client I'm piping the audio file into stdin of ffmpeg and listening to stderr of ffmpeg to determine when it's safe to send the buffer. The client is receiving the buffer and is doing everything properly until the line stated above. Here is some sample test code to reproduce the issue.

Server side:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var app       = express();
var webServer = http.createServer(app);
var io        = require('socket.io').listen(webServer, {log: false});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send(
    "<script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>\n"+
    "<script>var socket=io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000');</script>\n"+
    "<script src='/webaudio_file_cli.js'></script>"
    );
});
webServer.listen(3000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(webSocket) {

    var disconnect = '0';
    var count = 0;
    var audBuf = new Buffer([]);

    if (disconnect == '0') {
        console.log('new connection...');

        var inputStream = spawn('wget', ['-O','-','http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples/4353.mp3']);

        var ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', [
            '-i', 'pipe:0', // Input on stdin
            '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le', // PCM 16bits, little-endian
            '-ar', '24000', // Sampling rate
            '-ac', 1, // Mono
            '-f', 'wav',
            'pipe:1' // Output on stdout
        ], {stdio: ['pipe','pipe','pipe']});

            inputStream.stdout.pipe(ffmpeg.stdin);

            ffmpeg.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
                audBuf = Buffer.concat([audBuf,data]);
            });

            ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
            var _line = data.toString('utf8');
            if (_line.substring(0,5) == 'size=' && _line.indexOf('headers:') > -1) {
                console.log('completed...');
                webSocket.emit('audio',audBuf);
            }
        });
    }

    webSocket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('disconnecting...');
            disconnect=1;
    });
});
```

Client side (webaudio_file_cli.js):

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new AudioContext();
var source = context.createBufferSource();

var audioStack = [], audio = [];

socket.on('audio', function(data) {
    playAudio(data);
});

function playAudio(data) {
    // playback starting...
    audioStack = Int16Array(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < audioStack.length; i++) {
        audio[i] = (audioStack[i]>0)?audioStack[i]/32767:audioStack[i]/32768; // convert buffer to within the range -1.0 -> +1.0
    }

    var audioBuffer = context.createBuffer(1, audio.length, 24000);
    source.buffer.getChannelData(0).set(audio);
    source.buffer = audioBuffer;
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.start(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this example, you're accessing source.buffer.getChannelData before you set source.Buffer = audioBuffer.  Flip the order of those two lines, maybe?

Comment: It actually ended up being a two part problem. What you mentioned and audioStack = Int16Array(data); needed to be audioStack = new Int16Array(data);. It's weird because I've had both of those set the way they are with FF29 and it works fine.